# MySQL update with inner join taking too long

Tags: mysql, update, myisam, mysql-5.1

I have the following two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_products_temp` (
    `cd_id` INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cd_structure` MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
    `cd_smiles` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `cd_formula` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `cd_molweight` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cd_hash` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `cd_timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `cd_pre_calculated` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `iupac_name` VARCHAR(600) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `price_currency` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `price1` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `price2` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `price3` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
    `deleted_dt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`cd_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `tbl_products_temp_hx` (`cd_hash`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `tbl_products_temp_px` (`cd_pre_calculated`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `idx_iupac_name` (`iupac_name`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `idx_formula` (`cd_formula`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `idx_molweight` (`cd_molweight`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `idx_smiles` (`cd_smiles`(100)) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyIsam

CREATE TABLE `tbl_products_temp2` (
    `cd_id` INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cd_structure` MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
    `cd_smiles` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `cd_formula` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `cd_molweight` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cd_hash` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `cd_timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `cd_pre_calculated` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `iupac_name` VARCHAR(600) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `price_currency` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `price1` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `price2` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `price3` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
    `deleted_dt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`cd_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `tbl_products_temp_hx` (`cd_hash`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `tbl_products_temp_px` (`cd_pre_calculated`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `idx_iupac_name` (`iupac_name`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `idx_formula` (`cd_formula`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `idx_molweight` (`cd_molweight`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `idx_smiles` (`cd_smiles`(100)) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyIsam
```

Table tbl_products_temp has  241633 rows.
Table tbl_products_temp2 has 218380 rows.

I'm trying the following update query but its taking forever.

```
UPDATE tbl_products_temp
INNER JOIN tbl_products_temp2
ON tbl_products_temp.iupac_name = tbl_products_temp2.iupac_name
SET tbl_products_temp.price1 = tbl_products_temp2.price1,
    tbl_products_temp.price2 = tbl_products_temp2.price2,
    tbl_products_temp.price3 = tbl_products_temp2.price3,
    tbl_products_temp.price_currency = 'EUR'
```

When I run explain using the following I get:

```
explain select * from tbl_products_temp
inner join tbl_products_temp2 
on tbl_products_temp.iupac_name = tbl_products_temp2.iupac_name


id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref                                | rows   | Extra
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | SIMPLE      | tbl_products_temp2 | ALL  | idx_iupac_name | (NULL)         | (NULL)  | (NULL)                             | 218380 |
1  | SIMPLE      | tbl_products_temp  | ref  | idx_iupac_name | idx_iupac_name | 603     | mydb.tbl_products_temp2.iupac_name | 1      | Using where
```

How can I speed up this update query?

Comment: Are you updating all the rows?  Or do just a few match?

Comment: @RickJames around 21700 from tbl_products_temp2 match

Comment: 21K rows will take a long time.  What is the drawback in simply waiting?

Comment: @RickJames how long would it take? I've had it running for 3 hours now and I end up with `mysql Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

Comment: Aha!  You have just encountered a worse problem.  Because you are using MyISAM, _some_ of the rows got Updated, but you have no way to know which.  (With InnoDB, everything would have been rolled back, as if the Update had never happened.)  Well, maybe it is not so bad; it looks like that Update is "idempotent".  So...

Comment: Increase whatever "timeout" setting you hit and rerun the Update.  Or,...  Do the Update in batches:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks  (Adapt from Delete to Update)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are using MyISAM (:scream:)

## SUGGESTION #1 : Use a Bigger key_buffer_size

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL key_buffer_size = 256 * 1048576;
```

## SUGGESTION #2 : Use a Bigger join_buffer_size

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL join_buffer_size = 16 * 1048576;
```

You will have to restart the UPDATE JOIN

## Long Term : Make the tables InnoDB please

Comment: changed both tables to innodb and set key_buffer_size as suggested and it hasn't made any difference. I've had it running for 3 hours now and keep ending up with `mysql Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`